# Trouble instantiating class with reference to another class

Tags: c++, instantiation

I'm trying to instantiate a few classes, with references to the first class passed along.

The compiler gives me an error stating:  error: 'classData' is not a type.

ClassData hold some complicated data structures and has a bunch of accessors to that data.  ClassFunc has a bunch of functions that operate on that data.  Then the Work class does a bunch of work and occasionally needs to call a function in ClassB that will do some work on the data in ClassData.

Below is the code:

```
/////////////////////////
//ClassData.h
class ClassData {
public:
    ClassData(){
        // initialize a bunch of stuff
    };
    virtual ~ClassData(){};
}

/////////////////////////
//ClassFunc.h
#include "ClassData.h"

class ClassFunc {
public:
    ClassFunc(ClassData& in_classData) : classData(in_classData){};
    virtual ~ClassFunc();

    float updateEta(float deltaVJ, int column);

private:
    ClassData& classData;

};

/////////////////////////
//ClassFunc.cpp
#include "ClassFunc.h"

float ClassFunc::updateEta(float a, int b){
    float foo = 0.0
    // Do a bunch of work to foo
    return foo;

};

/////////////////////////
// Work.h
#include "ClassData.h"
#include "ClassFunc.h"

class Work{

public:
    Work(ClassData& in_class) :  classData(in_class){
        // initialize some stuff
    };
    ~Work(){};

    float updateTheta(int a, float b, float c);

private:
    ClassData& classData;
    ClassFunc classFunc(classData);  //// ERROR IS HERE
}

/////////////////////////
//  Work.cpp
#include "Work.h"
float Work::updateTheta(int a, float b, float c){

    // do some work first
    double foo = classFunc.updateEta(d, e);
    return foo
};
```

Comment: You're missing semicolons after class definitions. Is this your actuall code?

Comment: ClassB(Class A& in_classA) --> You seem to have an extra space "Class A" vs. "ClassA"

Comment: No wait, it's not a duplicate, sorry. I wish I could unvote to close.

Comment: Not my actual code - that is way to long to include here.  I very likely made a typo or two in typing up this quick example

Comment: **Here is actual code - shouldn't have any typos this way**

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler's right: `classA` isn't a type.  C++ is case-sensitive; `ClassA` is the type you're looking for (check the first line of `ClassB`'s constructor).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Answer After question modification**

`ClassFunc classFunc(classData);` is not valid syntax in the definition of a class. You will need to have this `classFunc` variable by either a set function or through the constructor.

However, writing just a setter will be difficult because your `ClassFunc` requires a `ClassData`. In order to work around this, you may need to modify your `ClassFunc` also.

Also, there is another error.  `ClassData` and `Work` are missing a ; at the end of its definition.

**Original Answer before question modification**

There are several errors in this code. Such as

`float ClassA::funcA{`

Should be

`float ClassA::funcA(){`

As other wise, it looks like a function definition.

Second, there is

`ClassB(Class A& in_classA): classA(in_classA){`

As it should be

`ClassB(ClassA& in_classA): classA(in_classA){`

As `Class A` is not a type.

Also, you are missing several semicolons but those should be obvious to spot.

Comment: As I wrote above, this was a quickly typed example.  Probably has a few typos in it.

Comment: That is ok, the main issue seemed to be your definition for funcA(). Once that is fixed, the rest was just typos.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot initialize member variables in the class declaration:

```
ClassFunc classFunc(classData);
```

Instead, initialize it in the initializer list of the constructor:

```
Work(ClassData& in_class) :  classData(in_class), classFunc(classData) {}
```

Comment: That fails with the error: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘ClassFunc&’ from expression of type ‘ClassData’